# Pressing back once is processed as twice

Tags: bug, android-app

I am viewing tags in Stack Overflow when I choose a tag the questions list for that tag appears I select one of the questions (everything is ok until now) but when I press back to go to the questions list the app takes me back to the tags list, this happens whether I have used the physical key or the button in the top left corner.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-N910C
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (N910CXXS2DQC5)